# Cauchy Sequences and Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be Cauchy sequences in a metric space $(X, d)$. Show that the sequence $(d(x_n, y_n))$ is a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

What is the significance of $\mathbb{R}$ in this question? Anyway, I am trying to think about what the theorem would tell me. If $(d(x_n, y_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence then for large $n$ the distance between $x_n$ and $y_n$ must be $\epsilon$ close. Thus $x_n$ and $y_n$ must converge to the same point

Other than that I am lost.

Comment: The significance of $\mathbb R$ in the question.  That is the space where $d(x_n,y_n)$ lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
By triangle inequality
$$d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,x_m)+d(x_m,y_m)+d(y_m,y_n)$$
so
$$d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_m,y_m)\leq d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_n,y_m)\tag{1}$$
and by the same method we have

$$d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_n,y_m)\tag{2}$$
hence with $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find
$$|d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_m,y_m)|\leq d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_n,y_m)$$
Now use $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences in a metric space $(X, d)$.

Comment: I see that you are using the standard metric for $\mathbb{R}$ is this the significance with $\mathbb{R}$ in the problem?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.